# link files within directory, with simple command similar to cp

Tags: linux, bash, ln

Where my question originated:

- When running `cp source/files.all destination/`, all the files within `source` will now also exist in `destination`

Question:

- What if I didn't want to duplicate the data from `source` into `destination`, but simply link them (**with absolute path**). Usually, I would run something like:

  `for f in $(ls source/); do ln -s $(pwd)/${f} $(pwd)/destination; done`

  Is there a simple command/tool that I can use (e.g. `ln -a source/files.all destination/`) which would create a softlink to all files in a directory, while *automatically adding the absolute path* as prefix. `ln -r` is close to what I need, but the absolute path, not the relative one?

Comment: No, the loop method is what you have available to you. In the directory you want to create links in, you can do something like `for i in source/*; do; [ -f "$i" ] && ln -s "$i"; done`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : Perhaps, the op should not parse the output of the `ls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually sort of found a simple way to do this:

Simply run `ln -s $(pwd -P)/source/* destination/`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `find "$PWD/source" -exec ln -s {} destination \;`. The absolute path used as the first argument to `find` will cause `{}` to be replaced by an absolute path to the source file for each command.

GNU `ln` supports the `-t` option to specify the destination directory, allowing you to use a more efficient invocation of `find`:

```
find "$PWD/source" -exec ln -s -t destination {} +
```

The `-exec ... +` form requires `{}` to be the last argument in the command; `-t` lets you move the destination argument up to accommodate that requirement.